# Дефект отображения следующей привилегии в профиле

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, привилегии, профиль-участника

Текст привилегии в 1000 реп. выходит за границы блока:

> [image: блок репутации]

Можно наблюдать по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/29893/ragmon?tab=topactivity).

Comment: А у меня нормально. Какой браузер используете?

Comment: @alexolut Chrome. кеш браузера чистил, но верстка этого блока всё равно плывёт.

Comment: у меня, правда, там другая совсем привилегия висит :) Так что не очень показательно.

Comment: @alexolut у меня эта проблема в браузерах: IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera. Ссылка на мой профиль: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/29893/ragmon?tab=topactivity

Comment: У меня слишком много репутации, чтобы это увидеть))

Comment: @Qwertiy надо просто меньше нарцисцизма :)

Comment: @alexolut, просто нет переключателя на привилегии... А хотелось посмотреть, что там в разметке)))

Comment: @Qwertiy переключатель не нужен чтобы посмотреть на профиле ТС.

Comment: @alexolut, на что жать? Я вот такое у него вижу: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFgVy.png UPDATE: разобрался: я метапрофиль смотрю вместо основного

Comment: @Qwertiy я же ссылку перенёс из коммента в вопрос. Надо на основном сайте смотреть, а не на Мете профиль.

Comment: Проблему подтверждаю - точно такая же ситуация. Во всех браузерах, в том числе и в Safari. P.S.: кстати говоря, к делу это не относится, но всё же - у меня такая же след. привилегия. =_=

Comment: Проблема у пользователей с рейтингом 500-999

Comment: @alexolut, такая же проблема у пользователей с рейтингом 2500-2999

Comment: @ragmon Добавьте, пожалуйста, тег `дизайн`. Потому что вопрос касается верстки. У меня нет права на редактировние вопроса. Решение привел ниже в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Проблема: переполнение текста в блоке привилегий

На странице профиля пользователя на вкладке «Активность» в блоке «След. привилегия» происходит переполнение текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Возможное решение

Изменить следующие стили (/* + */ — что было добавлено)

```css
.s-progress-bar._privilege .-info .-icon {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 14px;
    color: #6a737c;
    margin-left: 4px; /* + */
}

.s-progress-bar._privilege .-info .-label {
    margin-left: 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;  /* + */
    overflow: hidden;  /* + */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* + */
    display: inline-block;  /* + */
}
```

Не забыть к `span` добавить `title`. Чтобы при наведении можно было прочитать полностью статус.

```
<span class="g-col fl-none -label" title="Просмотр голосов, карточка участника, которую можно расширить">Просмотр голосов, карточка участника, которую можно расширить</span>
```

### Как будет выглядеть после изменений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эх, уже листья упали, а изменений нет

Answer (score 7):

Видимо, проблему снова нужно решать более коротким переводом, т.к. на enSO исходный текст помещается:

> [image: 1000 rep priviledge]

Я, правда, не помню, что там было раньше. Или проблема была всегда? Сейчас, насколько я знаю, происходит переделка по дизайну профиля.

Если определиться с переводом, то проблему дизайна будет легко решить.

Comment: Да заставить их давно пора нормально верстать!

Comment: Надо `line-height: 1;` и упихать перевод в 2 строки. А центрирование там нормально сделано, вроде.

Comment: @Qwertiy заставлять надо на MSE хотя бы. Но вообще там частенько и хорошо кладут на проблемы неанглийских сообществ. Действовать приходится только через CM.

Comment: overflow hidden

Comment: @Duoxx это Вы к чему?

Comment: можно прописать для этой таблички

Comment: @Duoxx Кажется, раньше и был `overflow:hidden` с плавным градиентом в цвет фона.

Comment: ["see votes, expandable usercard"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/48712674?q=see%20votes%2C%20expandable%20usercard), первоначально переведено было как "просмотр голосов, разворачиваемая карточка" (by NickVolynkin, 2 years ago), но вряд ли в одну строку умещалось (хотя скорее всего разбивалось только на 2 строки). Добавил вариант перевода "Просмотр голосов, расширяемая карточка участника".

Comment: @insolor надо старый дизайн где-то подсмотреть, так как я не помню, чтобы раньше тут была проблема. Видимо, перенос всё же был.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это решено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Only because text was shorten. I can't call it "fixed" (: