# Длительность конкурсных вопросов

Tags: предложение, конкурс

Мне кажется, что на StackOverflow на русском относительно мало конкурсных вопросов.

Может увеличить длительность конкурса до двух недель?

Сейчас в среднем где-то 10 конкурсных вопросов, если увеличить длительность конкурса в два раза, то их станет 20, вроде не слишком много.

Comment: Участники дорожат репутацией и не хотят её растрачивать на конкурсы направо и налево. Плюс, ответ на вопрос как правило появляется и безо всякого стимулирования.

Comment: @Arhad, да, всё так. Вот в тех редких случаях, когда ответа на вопрос нету и участник объявил конкурс, предлагается увеличить длительность конкурса, в некотором роде это может стимулировать участников объявлять конкурсы.

Comment: @diraria, в большинстве случаев, если ответа нет, значит вопрос не интересный. Если на такой вопрос назначить конкурс, то и отвечать будут ради повышения репутации. Если за 10 дней, пока действует конкурс, ответ не дан, то либо вопрос из какой-то очень узкой области, по которой здесь специалистов нет, либо вопрос совсем уж не интересн, либо оффтопичен по своей природе. Мое мнение - увеличивать длительность конкурса не нужно.

Comment: P.S. `Сейчас в среднем где-то 10 конкурсных вопросов, если увеличить длительность конкурса в два раза, то их станет 20, вроде не слишком много.` - во-первых не понятно, какой смысл в том, чтобы конкурсных вопросов становилось больше, во-вторых связь между количеством конкурсных вопросов и сроком конкурса довольно сомнительна. При том же среднем количестве добавляемых конкурсных вопросов в период времени, все равно через какое-то время общее количество сойдется к 8-10 вопросам, независимо от длительности конкурса.

Comment: @insolor, `При том же среднем количестве добавляемых конкурсных вопросов в период времени, все равно через какое-то время общее количество сойдется к 8-10 вопросам` вроде это не так, предположим что в день в среднем появляется `x` вопросов, тогда при длительности конкурса в `n` дней в `i`-ый день конкурсными будут вопросы, заданные в дни `[i - n, i]`, то есть в среднем `n * x` вопросов. Увеличиваем `n` (длительность конкурса) и `n * x` тоже увеличивается (то есть среднее число конкурсных вопросов)

Comment: @insolor, вообще не стоит беспокоиться, что это предложение реализуют) [Куда более очевидные предложения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5521/227016) могут оставаться без внимания достаточно долгое время)

Comment: @diraria, по поводу среднего количества - не все очевидно, можно при желании смоделировать и посмотреть. Я думаю, что при удвоении срока среднее количество конкурсных вопросов не удвоится (увеличится, но не в два раза, или останется таким же). Но реализовывать модель и проверять лень.

Comment: @insolor https://ideone.com/SxUBfh

Comment: @diraria, ок, допустим. В любом случае не вижу смысла ни в увеличении среднего количества конкурсных вопросов, ни в увеличении срока конкурса. По поводу другого "очевидного предложения" - у нас есть уже десяток (десятки?) натренированных биологических нейросетей, которые с данной задачей прекрасно справляются)

Comment: @insolor вот [ещё более очевидное предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5547/227016), которое не исправляют :)